# libstdc++.so.6 error on VS2022 compiled share library (.so)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, java-native-interface

I am working on a Spring Boot face detection application which will load JNI (*.so) to work.

[The face detection library git repo](https://gitee.com/cnsugar/seetaface6JNI-C) (Sorry, the repo in Chinese)

I compile the source by VS2022 for windows (*.dll) has no any problems, however it cannot work in ubuntu 22.04 or CentOS 7 as well.

It appear an error when I ran the SpringBoot Jar on uBuntu:

> [libstdc++.so.6+0xf5f2d] std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator::basic_string(std::string const&)

ubuntu environment:

- uBuntu 22.04
- gcc & g++ 11.3
- openJDK 1.8.0_362

I have stuck about 1 month and had try many suggestion, e.g.
downgrade gcc, use clang instead, try lower version ubuntu, different C++ version on VS2022 etc.
unfortunately it's not works.
I have not much experience on C or C++, so I would ask what cause this error or is it any way to display detail error message when the *.so run at runtime?

Anyway advice is great help and thanks.

The terminal screenshot:
[image]

VS2022 project preperties screenshot:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The first thing I would try is to follow the instructions to enable core dumps (see the error message) and then load that core dump into the g++ debugger (it's called gdb). That might give you a call stack that gives you some idea of what is going on.